# Can anyone help me troubleshoot a bellman equation’s value function?

Tags: probability, optimization, stochastic-processes, recursion, stochastic-analysis

Question: How would I go about deriving the values for a Bellman Equation’s value function?

i.e. suppose I have the following maximization problem:

$\max_{c_t\geq 0, k_{t+1}\geq 0}$$E_0$$[\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\beta^{t}\ln c_t]$ s.t. $k_{t+1}+c_t=A^{1-\alpha}_tk^{\alpha}_t$ $\beta \in (0,1)$; $\alpha\in (0,1)$

I know that I am supposed to “guess” the value function and I have this $V(A_t,k_t)=X+Y \ln(A_t)+Z \ln(k_t)$.

This is where the problem shows up. I have no idea as to how I would begin to derive the values of X,Y and Z to confirm the values. Can anyone “point” me in the right direction as it where?

I assume I probably have to rewrite my bellman, but I have yet to learn how to properly rewrite a bellman out of the sigma notation form.

Comment: First write the bellman equation for the value function $V(A_t,k_t)$.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response. Did I not write the bellman equation in the problem above? The bit after the “I have the following maximization problem?”

Comment: It is not in Bellman form. The Bellman equation is a recursive equation for $V(A_t,k_t)$.

Comment: So... how do I generate the Bellman equation? Would it not just be time t, t+1, t+n, summed?

Comment: $V(A,k)=max_{c\geq 0} [ln c+ \beta V(A',k') ]$ s.t. $k'=A^{1-\alpha}k^{\alpha}-c$, where $k'$, $A'$ are next period values.

Comment: Do you understand where this comes from? Then plug in your guess for $V(A,k)$

Comment: I think so, but I do have one clarifying question. Why would we not set our constraint function up so that the LHS is $c_t$? Is that just because our value function is $V(A,k)$?

Comment: Anyways, thank you for the assistance. I will try and see how using the Lagrange method works to give me a solution.